# Multiple Rails submit buttons in one Form (one remote)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, action

Is there any way to add two submit buttons in one Form and one of the request should be remote? I mean without using extra JS.

My question is related to [Rails: Multi-submit buttons in one Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332449/rails-multi-submit-buttons-in-one-form), but what differs is the remote.

Comment: Did you find an answer for your question?

Comment: Not really, you could try to use another form or extra JS.

Comment: Why do you think you can't do this?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably to have 2 different forms on the same page. See below.

HelloController

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
  def say_hello
    puts params

    respond_to do |format|
     format.html 
     format.js
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
TwoForms::Application.routes.draw do
  get "hello/get_ready"
  post "hello/say_hello"

  root to: "hello#get_ready"
end
```

views/hello/get_ready.html.erb

```
<h2>Regular hello</h2>
<%= button_to "Regular Hello", hello_say_hello_path, name: "regular" %>

<h2>Ajaxy hello</h2>
<%= button_to "Ajaxy Hello", hello_say_hello_path, name: "ajaxy", remote: true %>
```

views/hello/say_hello.html.erb

```
Success (regular)!

<%= params %>
```

views/hello/say_hello.js.erb

```
alert("Success (Ajaxy)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this:

Create a bind on the "remote" submit button: #remote_btn_submit

```
$("#remote_btn_submit").on("click", function(){ //click it's not the best bind perhaps input?
  $("#my_form").data("remote", "true");
  //or
  //$("#my_form").attr("data-remote", "true");
});
```

You will need a preventDefault on the remote submit also

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12504660/4469336) to make the form remote or non-remote via JQuery when clicking the corresponding buttons. To do this, add e.g. `class: 'local-button'` and `class: 'remote-button'`, to your submit buttons, `id: 'my-form'` to your form, and the following code (CoffeeScript):

```
$(".remote-button").click ->
  $("#my-form").attr("data-remote", true)
$(".local-button").click ->
  $("#my-form").removeAttr("data-remote")
  $("#my-form").removeData("remote");
```