# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken when disable JS/Ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two forms with option `remote: true`; one sends an Ajax request to `create` action and the other one sends an Ajax request to `destroy` action.

All work fines when JavaScript is enabled, but if I disable JavaScript, then I click, I get this error:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken PersonsController#create
```

Why this error is shown, and how can I fix it ?

note: I'm using Rails 4

### Update

When I use a normal form without option `remote: true`, rails automatically inserts a hidden field for an authentication token, but when I use `remote: true` in my form there is no such field in the HTML code. It seems like when there is `remote` option, then Rails handles the authentication token differently, so how I can get this to work in both cases?

Comment: medBo, check if your form has `csrf` token inside in html output. If no, that may be the reason.

Comment: @BillyChan there is no csrf token inside html of form ! i'm using rails 4 i think this is by design ? or what ?

Comment: medBo, check my update.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Bizarrely, this behaviour was changed in rails 4. http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-4-whats-new/

Rails forms now will not render the CSRF field in the form unless you explicitly define it as an option to your form:

```
<%= form_for @some_model, :remote => true, :authenticity_token => true do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Adding this option allows you to gracefully degrade to a HTML fallback if Javascript is switched off.

Comment: yes @DanGarland exactly this is due to problem of fragment caching as the author in the the link above describe :)

Comment: @DanGarland thanks. I had this issue with remote form which under certain conditions I dynamically convert to non-remote form by removing data-remote.

Comment: as soon as I added `authenticity_token: true` to the `bootstrap_form_for` call, I get an `UnknownFormat` error, meaning the `remote: true` is no longer being recognized.  Previously, I did not have the `authenticity_token: true` on the form and received the error message that led me to this post.  Would you know why adding the `authenticity_token: true` to the `bootstrap_form_for` would cause the `remote: true` to stop working?  The form has the `data-remote="true"` in the html, so I'm not sure what the issue is here: `UnknownFormat` pointing to my `repond_to do |format| format.js end`

Comment: I have the same problem of @JakeSmith

Comment: This is an old question but I'm getting the same error as Jake Smith and @rizidoro -- did either of you find a solution?

Comment: A BIG thank you guy, we spent a lot of time investigating this strange behaviour in our app.

Comment: The same problem as @JakeSmith any solution?

Answer (score 33):

Me too faced the same problem. I have used form_tag to create custom remote form, but i got the the following error,

```
 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

I found that this is because in rail 4 wont add authenticity toke by default, so i added the following line in application.rb file,

```
 config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true
```

which automatically verify the toke when submitting the remote forms. This solves the problem for me. Hope this will help some one.

Comment: Nice explanation at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html: `config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms` allows you to set the default behavior for authenticity_token in forms with :remote => true. By default it's set to false, which means that remote forms will not include authenticity_token, which is helpful when you're fragment-caching the form. Remote forms get the authenticity from the meta tag, so embedding is unnecessary unless you support browsers without JavaScript....

Answer (score 5):

In my case i just had to add this line in my page:

```
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no csrf field(a hidden field) inside the form, the submission can't be authenticated by Rails server.

If you make the form by `form_tag`, this situation will happen. The better approach is to use `form_for` for a resource(new object or an existing object in db) and csrf field will be built by Rails automatically.

Comment: hi @BillyChan my problem isn't with ajax request, i use already remote: true and it works fine, my problem is when i disable javascript and i try to submit the form such as normal form