# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi sir in rails 4 while using form_for also getting above error in google i read about this and follow that but even also i am getting same error
if i disable in application controller and added protect_from_forgery with: :null_session it is working but when i submit the form_for form i am getting params missing or params should not empty .
i refered this link  [i refered  link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452853/actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken-when-disable-js-ajax-request)even also not working

Error in the log file
 Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

code view

```
<%= form_for @user  do |f| %>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </p>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :gender %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :gender %>
  </p>

= f.fields_for :address do |p| %>
   <p>
    <%= p.label :city %><br />
    <%= p.text_field :city %>
  </p>
    <p>
    <%= p.label :state %><br />
    <%= p.text_field :state %>
  </p>
 <p>
    <%= p.label :country %><br />
    <%= p.text_field :country %>
  </p>
   <p>
    <%= p.label :postal_code %><br />
    <%= p.text_field :postal_code %>
  </p>
<% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

if set protect_from_forgery with: :null_session and if submit the form 
than i will getting one more error

param is missing or the value is empty:

userActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):

Comment: `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` add this to application_controller

Comment: Thank you for quick response but i edited above in application_controller but i am getting error param is missing or the value is empty: user

Comment: Do you have `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in the `<head>` section of your layout.html.erb?

Comment: yes have in application.html.erb